# How does 'require' operates differently from 'import' es6?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, ecmascript-6, require, immutable.js

I am encountering a behaviour that I can't explain.
Depending on using `import` or `require`, this test successes (`import`) or fails (`require`).

In case of fail, I have the following error:

> PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 7 0.0.0) immutability a number is immutable FAILED undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'expect((0, _immutable.List)([1])).toEqualImmutable((0, _immutable.List)([1]))')

Here is the code :

```
import { Map, List } from 'immutable';
const expect = require("expect");
// import expectImmutable from "expect-immutable";
const expectImmutable = require("expect-immutable");

expect.extend(expectImmutable);

describe("immutability", () => {
    describe("a number", () => {
        function increment(currentState) {
            return currentState + 1;
        }
        it("is immutable", () => {
            expect(List([1])).toEqualImmutable(List([1]));
            expect(Map({ a: 1 })).toEqualImmutable(Map({ a: 1 }));
            let state = 42;
            let nextState = increment(state);

            expect(List([nextState])).toEqualImmutable(List([43]));
            expect(List([state])).toEqualImmutable(List([42]));
        });
    });
});
```

Does anyone have an explanation of what is happening behind the scene?

Comment: As soon as you're transpiling it anyway - why don't you check the difference between the code with `require` and transpiled `import` (which will be `require` as well)?

Comment: you're probably looking for the default property in the object you require, try  `require("expect").default` and `require("expect-immutable").default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @zerkms and @maioman your advices have really helped.
You were right @maioman, It was due to the export syntax used by the library.

es6 :

```
export default foo;
```

require :

```
module.exports = foo;
```

So when needed to require an es6 written export, we should handle the default keyword.

```
require("foo").default;
```